# Como validar formulario php

Tags: php, html5, php5

Buenas soy nuevo en PHP estoy realizando un formulario que registro con la bd sql server

Dentro del formulario solo tiene estos campos
Tengo un inconveniente esperó que me puedan ayudar cada vez que yo ingreso el dni o el nombre y le pulso registrar y como hay una validación dentro del PHP se borra lo que he escrito . y veo que se actualiza lo que yo quisiera saber como puedo validar un formulario sin que se actualice la pagina y lo que he escrito antes se quede y no se borre

```
Dni : <input type="text" name="t1" />
Nombre :<input type="text" name="t2" />

Registrar : <button type="submit" name="reg" value="registrar" > </button>

<?
If(isset(reg).....

Valida campos 
....

?>
```

Comment: Puedes utilizar [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) o [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) si estás usando jQuery

Comment: @kacospro mi hermano podrías hacer un ejemplito si fuera tan amable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma de hacer una petición sin recargar toda la página es utilizar [AJAX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX)

Existe la forma con puro javascript con [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) o a mi criterio muy personal la mas simple que es utilizando [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) de esta forma

```
var request = $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/path/a/tu-url.php',
    data: $( "form" ).serialize()
});

//Manejo cuando la petición termina
request.done(function( event ) {
    // Aquí puedes redirigir si no hay fallos
});

//Manejo cuando la petición falla
request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

O incluso mas simple con [$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) de esta manera

```
$.post( "/path/a/tu-url.php", $( "form" ).serialize());
```

Aquí un ejemplo funcional de como funciona una ejecución AJAX de una form

```js
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  $('.invalid-helper').remove();

  var validates = true;
  var $inputs = $(this).children('input');

  $.each($inputs, function() {
    // Revisamos que los campos no estén vacíos
    if ($(this).val() === '') {
      validates = false;
      $(this).after('<span class="invalid-helper">El campo no puede estar vacío</span>');
    }
  });

  if (!validates) {
    return;
  }

  $.post(
      "https://hookb.in/vaP3LY5a",
      $("form").serialize()
    ).done(function() {
      console.log('Éxito');
    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log('Falló');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form" action="https://requestb.in/y6crnty6" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="input_1">
  <br/>
  <input type="text" name="input_1">
  <br/>
  <input type="text" name="input_1">
  <br/>
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda, si no dejame un comentario :)

Comment: Mi hermano una consulta ahí donde lo pondría na validación de los campos

Comment: @Pierro Depende de donde quieras hacerlo, lo ideal sería hacerlo en tu código php, si editas tu pregunta con el código php y tu código de la form te podría dar una respuesta mas completa

Comment: Y como hago para que en mi PHP llame ese ajax @kacospro

Comment: @Pierro Tu php no llama el ajax, el ajax se ejecuta en cliente en la página web y este llama a tu php, editaré mi respuesta con un ejemplo mas claro de como usar ajax, dame unos minutos

Comment: Listo @Pierro a ver si con eso te queda mas claro

Comment: es decir tan solo en ajax pongo  .form  automático ya sabe el ajax que campos están vacío y muestra un mensaje que campo falta por llenar

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71856/discussion-between-kacospro-and-pierro).